# Regex to match repeating groups only capturing one group

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to match the string

```
6 cakes 5 donuts 12 muffins
```

into three groups viz. `6 cakes`, `5 donuts`, `12 muffins`. To achieve this I've used the regex

```
([\d]{1}[\s]{1}[\w]*)
```

But the problem is its only matching the first group `6 cakes` and ignoring the rest. How can I change it to make the group repeating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to obtain a [MatchCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection(v=vs.90).aspx) with [`Regex.Matches`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.90).aspx) and get the matches. The regex can be

```
\d+\s+\w+
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cd%2B%5Cs%2B%5Cw%2B&i=6%20cakes%205%20donuts%2012%20muffins)

In C#,

```
var str = "6 cakes 5 donuts 12 muffins";
var rx = new Regex(@"\d+\s+\w+");
var coll = rx.Matches(str);
foreach (Match m in coll)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/qPx90y)

You can also use LINQ:

```
var str = "6 cakes 5 donuts 12 muffins";
var rx = new Regex(@"\d+\s+\w+");
var coll = rx.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfect. Only catch is if the food name itself contains some number then the patterns breaks. For e.g. `3 beers 5 chicken 65 9 cakes` would break.

Comment: You can use the [`\d+(?:\s+\d+)*\s+\w+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cd%2b(%3f%3a%5cs%2b%5cd%2b)*%5cs%2b%5cw%2b&i=3+beers+5+chicken+65+9+cakes) regex.

Comment: This just missed by goal by an tiny bit. Now its matching `3 beers`, `5 chicken` and `65 9 cakes` instead it should match `3 beers`, `5 chicken 65` and `9 cakes`.

Comment: How come you know that `65` pertains to `chicken`? What is the logic behind? All numbers up to the last followed with spaces pertain to the previous entry?

Comment: I mean if there are more than one consecutive numbers then the first number belongs to the previous group and not the succeeding one.

Comment: This one `\d+(?:\s+\d+)*\s+\w+(?:\s+\d+)*(?=\s+\d+|$)` works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check this one, too: [`\d+(?:\s+\d+)*\s+\w+(?:\s+\d+(?=\s+\d+))?`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cd%2b(%3f%3a%5cs%2b%5cd%2b)*%5cs%2b%5cw%2b(%3f%3a%5cs%2b%5cd%2b(%3f%3d%5cs%2b%5cd%2b))%3f&i=3+beers+56+455+5+chicken+65+9+cakes+5+cups)

Comment: Great, please consider accepting the answer if it works for you and upvoting if it proved helpful to you.